# Too many www-data process on Apache2 server, WordPress website won't work

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache

On my website (WordPress), some times it runs so many processes as shown in the screenshot (Putty - top)

Then the site won't work.

Please help to resolve this.

[image]

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Also, this is not a programming question (thus off topic on stackoverflow). Please see [help/on-topic] and try https://superuser.com or https://wordpress.stackexchange.com. But even there, "the site won't work" is not a proper problem description. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a lot of httpd processes because you have a lot of users accessing your site. If not, please edit your question with details about the load on the server.

I recently had the same problem and I was using the same amount of memory as you. First I adjusted the swap space, because the default swap space is too small. The details of how to do this depend on your particular Linux distribution but if you google it you can easily find instructions.

Eventually though, I rented another server with twice as much memory. This is the best long-term solution.

Comment: I shifted to nginx. Now it's solved